# How to find AS code in FLA file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So one programmer maded a flash app, but when i open it whit adobe flash, i'can find any code inside, but the application works, i've tried to see in the frames actions, but nothing, the library is only with movieclips, any ideas please?

Comment: also I have an swc file near, but it doesn't open it with adobe flash, how can i solve this?, but as far as i know the swc file contains only movieclips without code yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWC libraries contains AS classes as well. There are some explorers for SWC files, for example Flash Builder 4.6 supports it. You can also rename *.swc file to *.zip and check the catalog.xml file for class names and use any swf decompiler for browsing library.swf for sources.

Comment: thank you very much, never knowed that swc can be renamed to zip.. that helped!